# Twitter integration in iOS 5.0

Tags: twitter, ios5

**I have added the Twitter.framework and Accounts.framework.

And imported the Twitter.h header file.

But I am getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'tweetSheet'"**

```
Class TWTweetComposeViewController = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");
if(TWTweetComposeViewController != nil) {



    //For iOS 5.0 onwards
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        //Create the tweet sheet
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        //Customize the tweet sheet here
        //Add a tweet message
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:[[self getShareContent] objectForKey:@"twitterContent"]];

        //Set a blocking handler for the tweet sheet
        tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                                UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tweeted"
                                                                                    message:@"You successfully tweeted"
                                                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                [alertView show];
                                [alertView release];
            } else if (TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                                UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ooops..."
                                                                                    message:@"Something went wrong, try again later"
                                                                                   delegate:self
                                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                [alertView show];
                                [alertView release];
            }

            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        };

        //Show the tweet sheet!
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];

    } else {

            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                message:@"You need to configure your Twitter account in the Settings"
                                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];


    }

}
```

Comment: [Here](http://dummycode.com/b/3) is a great post on integrating Twitter API with iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is confused because you've created a variable (`TWTweetComposeViewController`) which has the same name as a class name.  Change the first 2 lines to:

```
Class tweetComposeViewController = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");
if(tweetComposeViewController != nil) {
```

...and you should be all good.